# How can I make my privacy alert in-front of all DIVs, RevSlider etc

Tags: php, css, cookies, privacy

Check out my site; http://sequoiasystems.org.

I included a a privacy alert because of new EU Regulation, but the alert goes behind some of my website components like other DIVs and Revolution slider...

I have tried some CSS, but nothing seems to work.

Comment: give the div a z-index thats higher than whats it's behind.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can probably fix it by giving it a high z-index.  You can do it two ways.

1.) Use inline style attribute:

```
<div id="myDiv" style="z-index:100;">This is my privacy warning</div>
```

2.) Use CSS with a class:

```
 .myclass {

    z-index: 100;
}

<div id="myDiv" class="myClass">This is my privacy warning</div>
```

Comment: Thanks. It actually still goes behind my Revolution Slider; http://sequoiasystems.org. Thanks for your support.

Comment: Yup, no problem..  Sometimes you have to keep upping the z-index until your sure it passed any other z-index being called on the page.  Please mark as the accepted answer.  Cheers!